# Reading a int[] from java properties file

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, properties-file

I have method which takes an `int[]` as input.

```
methodABC(int[] nValue)
```

I would like to take this nValue from a Java property file

```
nValue=1,2,3
```

How do I read this from the config file or do I have to store this in a different format?

What I tried is (`changing the nValue to 123 instead of 1,2,3`):

```
int nValue = Integer.parseInt(configuration.getProperty("nnValue"));
```

How do we do this?

Comment: Not sure if duplicate, but this may be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015491/better-way-to-represent-array-in-java-properties-file

Comment: If `nVAlueString="1,2,3";` you can do : `nValueString.split(",");` and then parse the resulting array.

Answer (score 6):

Raw-properties file is so 90`s  :) you should use a json file instead,

anyways:

if you have this:

```
nValue=1,2,3
```

then read nValue, split that to comma and stream/loop parsing to int

## example:

```
String property = prop.getProperty("nValue");
System.out.println(property);
String[] x = property.split(",");
for (String string : x) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(string));
}
```

since java 8:

```
int[] values = Stream.of(property.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
for (int i : values) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that JSON is always best. It just usually is. key/value pairing has its place though.

Comment: Hi @JoPeyper, thanks for the comment...  well json is an impoved alternative to xml... which kills such a problems when lists and arrays are present in the config

Comment: Yes, for lists, JSON (and XML) is better than properties. We agree!

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.split` and `Integer.parseInt`. With Streams you can do it in one line:

```
String property = configuration.getProperty("nnValue")
int[] values = Stream.of(property.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **read the value (`nValue=1,2,3`) as string only** and `split` the string (with `","`) then convert to an `int[]` array as shown below:

```
//split the input string
String[] strValues=configuration.getProperty("nnValue").split(",");
int[] intValues = strValues[strValues.length];//declare int array
for(int i=0;i<strValues.length;i++) {
    intValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(strValues[i]);//populate int array
}
```

Now, you can call the method by passing the `intValues` array as shown below:

```
methodABC(intValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring, you can read directly arrays in you properties (but also maps, if you need more complex data). E.g. in application.properties:

```
nValue={1,2,3}
```

and in your code:

```
@Value("#{${nValue}}")
Integer[] nValue;
```

then you can use nValue where you want.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to read property of Property file in java:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
    prop.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    //get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually addressing the question.