# how to read from property file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, properties-file

I am able to read (value of 'fruits') from property file in my spring boot application, successfully using @Value as below.

```
@Value("${fruits}")
private String[] fruitarray;
```

from the below

## file:applicaton.properties

```
#section_1
fruits=apple,mango,banana
#section_2
apple.native=aaaa
apple.cost=100
apple.name=xxyyzz
```

Now, I would like to know, how can I access the key-values from the section_2 of the properties file dynamically.
I mean,... in our above code we already got array of fruits and set it to 'fruitarray' using @Value. Now how would I be accessing value for 'apple.native' by using fruitarray[0] variable in java/spring-boot way?

Thanks

Comment: Simply use: @Value("${apple. native}")

Comment: You can use maps: Have a look here https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-lists-maps-example/

Comment: Try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321542/2652269 Use dellimiter ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get all the properties as a Bean and access dynamically to your properties while looping over the fruits list :

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
env.getProperty(fruits[i] + ".native");
...
```

Source : http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#usage

Comment: spring boot by default provides the application.properties injected so no need to do this all.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as that:

```
    @Value("${apple.native}")
    private String Native;

    @Value("${apple.cost}")
    private Double cost;

    @Value("${apple.name}")
    private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the properties file in the following way also

```
key.0=value0
key.1=value1
```

/** Return array from properties file. Array must be defined as "key.0=value0", "key.1=value1", ... */
public List getSystemStringProperties(String key) {

```
// result list
List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

// defining variable for assignment in loop condition part
String value;

// next value loading defined in condition part
for(int i = 0; (value = YOUR_PROPERTY_OBJECT.getProperty(key + "." + i)) != null; i++) {
    result.add(value);
}

// return
return result;
```

}